# A error when call this method: curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)

Tags: ssl, curl

```
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!SSL_COMP_set0_compression_methods()    未知
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods() 未知
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!SSL_library_init() 未知
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!Curl_ossl_init() 行 738 C
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!Curl_ssl_init() 行 256  C
MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!curl_global_init(long flags) 行 240 C
```

> MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!NetClient::HttpsGet(const std::string & strUrl, std::string & strResponse, int nTimeOut) 行 84  C++
> MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!ClientNetTask::DoWork() 行 37   C++
> MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!FQueuedThreadWin::Run() 行 258  C++
> MiniWorldStudioHub_d.exe!FQueuedThreadWin::_ThreadProc(void * pThis) 行 236  C++
> [外部代码]

I call this interface in a child thread, but this error also occurs when I place it in the main thread.Any help to me.